# helping business the "online" way

Tags: tenses, sentence

can I use this sentences in my slogan?

> helping business the "online" way

or

> growing business the "online" way

I get the idea from this sentences "helping business the right way."

or I must add a "through".

helping business through the "online" way

It looks strange for me. Please correct me if it is not suitable.

Comment: This native speaker immediately knew what you were shooting for, but it might be colloquial american sales-speak.

Comment: Experience has shown that when it comes to slogans, you can do anything you want, and grammar will take a back seat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should note that, *online* is not widely recognised as a word, though I use it all the time, and people will understand it.

I really don't like the term *the online way*. It doesn't make a lot of sense and sounds very 20th century. For a slogan, I think this is a bad choice. Perhaps consider terms like *web presence* or *in the Cloud*.

Comment: What is "the web way" though? I just don't like the phrase, whether you use web, online or anything else. Remember the word *web* is a proper noun when used to describe the Web, so it should be capitalised, but not when used to define things as web related, like *website* or *web app*. How about something like **Growing Business in the Cloud**?

Comment: sounds good to me. luckily I ask first before I put it in my namecard. Thanks a lot.